# Pickle load `__dict__` doesn't load all attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, pickle

#### Question

I'm trying to save a class `Level` to file. But my recently added attribute `particle` is not included when I run the following minimal test case (python 3.7). It crashes on the last line. Why is it not included when pickling?

#### Short explaination of code

The `Vector3d` class inherits `numpy.ndarray` and then `Particle` inherits `Vector3d` with an added attribute `particle`. `Level` then contains a list containing a `Particle`. This particle contains the attribute before saving since the first print statement works, but the second doesn't.

```py
import numpy as np
import pickle

class Vector3d(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, x, y, z):
        self = np.asarray([x,y,z], dtype=int).view(cls)
        return self

class Particle(Vector3d):

    def __new__(cls, particle: int, x: int, y: int, z: int):
        self = Vector3d.__new__(cls, x, y, z)
        self.particle = particle

        return self

class Level:
    def __init__(self):
        self.particles = [
            Particle(42, 1, 2, 3)
        ]

    def save(self):
        save_file = open("tmp.level", 'wb')
        pickle.dump(self.__dict__, save_file)
        save_file.close()

    def load(self):

        with open("tmp.level", 'rb') as load_file:
            loaded_level = pickle.load(load_file)

            self.__dict__ = loaded_level

if __name__ == "__main__":
    level = Level()
    level.save()

    saved_level = Level()
    saved_level.load()

    print(f"original particle = {level.particles[0].particle}")
    print(f"loaded particle = {saved_level.particles[0].particle}")
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Alright, I'll fix.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how's this?

Comment: I suspect this has to do with how `numpy.ndarray` objects implement pickling

Comment: TBH using numpy like this doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I initially thought numpy would be good as a base class, because there are so many vector problems that have been solved for numpy vectors, but I'm not sure I really benefitted that much from it.

Comment: Because `numpy` is meant to be used as large, vectorized array operations. You should represent your data as one big `(N, 3)` array, not many `Vector3d` objects. Or else you might as well use lists.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're probably right. It seems that the numpy methods I use support normal arrays, so I don't even need numpy-arrays for that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga although, after implementing addition, subtraction, multiplication, negative vectors etc. I once again think numpy arrays were useful as a base class.

Comment: Using a list based vector class instead of numpy array did solve the pickling problem.